# Fedora 18 - error [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid

Tags: linux, fedora, ssl, ssl-certificate, fedora-18

When i run the command:

```
sudo yum install perl-bioperl
```

I get the error

```
 [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid.
```

My system details are:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 2 20:28:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help me figuring out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this problem is that the date on your computer is wrong -- outside of the expiration period for the server's security certificate. It *could* be something else (data corruption, an attempted hijack, or Fedora's server legitimately having a problem), but time error is the most likely and where you should start to debug.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this hint https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53905

> Issue
>
> Cannot install packages because of error: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot
>   be verified or peer cert invalid
>
> or
>
> Error: failed to retrieve repodata/-primary.xml.gz from
>   rhel-x86_64-server-6
>
> error was [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified
>   or peer cert invalid
>
> In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 an error is seen
>   when trying to change the mirrorlist= URL from http to https in a yum
>   .repo file, but this works on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.

Comment: Unable to view the subscriber content :(

Comment: I already included the content of that page in the answer.

Comment: changing HTTPS to Http doesnt work for me..

Comment: This is not the entire content of that page.